# Webpack file loader does not copy files

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader

In an Angular2 application, I have a file loader setup in webpack config, like so:

```
  {
    test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'file?name=/assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
  }
```

I also have this elsewhere in the config:

```
modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
```

As I understand, the file loader searches the node_modules folder for any files that match the expression given (in this case font files), and copies them over to the `/assets/fonts` folder in the build output. However this does work, as no files actually get copied to to the destination folder. What am I missing?

On a side note, I also would like to know how conflicts are handled, as there could be files in `node_modules` in multiple packages with the same name.

More information:
`vendor.scss` file includes the following:
    $zmdi-font-path: "assets/fonts";
    @import "~material-design-iconic-font/scss/material-design-iconic-font.scss";

The sass-loader eventually applies this to result in the following css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Material';
src:url('assets/fonts/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.woff2?v=2.2.0') format('woff2'),url('assets/fonts/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.woff?v=2.2.0') format('woff'),url('assets/fonts/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.ttf?v=2.2.0}') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

The two steps above will cause a request from the browser to the font file at `assets/fonts/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.woff2?v=2.2.0`. This does not happen until runtime obviously. Where would I `require` the file so that it is copied to assets/fonts at build time?

I am also using the `sass-loader` in the pipeline:
    {
    test: /.scss$/,
    loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
    }

and include the sass in my component like this:

```
styleUrls: [
'./../assets/scss/main.scss'
]
```

I can see that the css is included in the HTML when seen from the browser, but calls to the fonts return 404.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works a little differently:

It does not simply copy all files matching the test regex. It will copy all required files matching the regex. What this means is that somewhere in your code, you must require a css file (or sass or less) that loads the font. Webpack will then make sure the font is copied over to your assets folder.

Note, you can drop the `/` in front of `/assets/fonts/...`.

**EDIT**
Make sure to require your sass file `vendor.scss` somewhere at the beginning of your app inside your js.

## Example

```
require('./path-to-vendor/vendor.scss');
```

Webpack will then load the file and prepare any dependencies for you. It looks weird to require your sass inside js, but that's how it works. :)

Comment: Thanks. Added more information to my question above. I will remove the leading slash on assets.

Comment: What if you don't have a JS app file?

Comment: Can you elaborate @evolutionxbox

Comment: I'm using webpack to build my JS, but the JS does not control asset loading, or routing, and the like.

Comment: people don't use require they import stuff